# How can I programatically identify video frames containing a fixed rectangular area of a certain color?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have video material containing frames with a rectangular area of uniform color interspersed with other content.  I would like to identify these frames, with the intent of removing them. The technique [discussed here](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/23665/find-frames-in-video-that-contain-an-image)  looks promising, as does the ffmpeg *blackdetect* filter on its own.  However, I need to be able to specify the color of the rectangle for each video.  It is not always black.

Answer (score 0):

Identify a logo should be part of the CV. My suggestion is to use the idea of checking the logo from png (https://ai-facets.org/robust-logo-detection-with-opencv/) and modify the code to read a frame from a video (https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html)

Hope this help